# ScriptingBridge iTunesTrack VS. iTunesFileTrack - Sandbox Error

Tags: applescript, itunes, scripting-bridge, applescript-objc

I have an AppleScript-ObjC app, which is sandboxed, and am running into an issue with trying to get or set properties of an iTunes track. Oddly, I can successfully run the get/set methods when working with an iTunesTrack object, but cannot when working with an iTunesFileTrack object.

Example:

```
    set iTunesAppObject to current application's SBApplication's applicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.iTunes")
    set trackToEdit to iTunesAppObject's currentTrack()
    set trackPersistentID to trackToEdit's persistentID()
    trackToEdit's setName_("TEST NAME") -- this works, trackToEdit is an iTunesTrack object

    -- GET ALL SOURCES FROM ITUNES
    set iTunesSources to iTunesAppObject's sources()

    -- REPEAT FOR EVERY SOURCE
    repeat with aSource in iTunesSources

        -- LOOK FOR MAIN LIBRARY SOURCE
         if (aSource's |kind|()) is 1.800169826E+9 then
             set mainLibrary to aSource
             exit repeat
         end if

    end repeat

    set libraryPlaylist to mainLibrary's |libraryPlaylists|() -- GET LIBRARY PLAYLIST
    set libraryPlaylist to libraryPlaylist's objectAtIndex_(0)
    set allTracksInPlaylist to libraryPlaylist's |fileTracks|() -- GET ALL TRACKS IN PLAYLIST

    -- SET UP PREDICATE TO FIND TRACK WITH ID
    set searchPredicate to current application's NSPredicate's predicateWithFormat_(("persistentID == " & quoted form of (trackPersistentID as text)))
    allTracksInPlaylist's filterUsingPredicate_(searchPredicate) -- FILTER ARRAY
    set trackToEdit to allTracksInPlaylist's objectAtIndex_(0) -- GET REMAINING ITEM IN ARRAY, RETURNS iTunesFileTrack OBJECT


log trackToEdit -- returns a seemingly valid iTunesFileTrack object     
trackToEdit's setName_("TEST NAME") -- does NOT work, result in sandbox dispatch deny error in Console.app
log trackToEdit's |name|() -- does NOT work, returns null/missing value
```

Everything works when the app is not sandboxed. I have added pretty much every entitlement to my project, including:

```
com.apple.iTunes.library.read-write
com.apple.iTunes.user-interface
com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo
com.apple.iTunes.playback
```

Can anyone think of a way to get around this? Is is possible to "convert" an iTunesFileTrack object to an iTunesTrack object? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bless your heart. try this out:

```
property aTrack : missing value

on getTrack_(sender)

tell application "iTunes"
set aTrack to (get current track)
end tell

end getTrack_

on renameTrack_(sender)
set name of aTrack to "whatever"
end renameTrack_
```

Comment: i owe u some wings bro. i set my ball down and forgot i pooped in the water.